# How can I install and run .xpi browser extension in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, firefox-extensions, privacy

I'm trying to open a ".xpi" file in Windows 7. The file is a browser extension for avoiding data tracking designed to run under Mozilla: DoNotTrack+. ver 2.0.8.

**Can anyone tell me either, how to open the file and install the extension, or if there is a reasonable free alternative that works well for windows 7?**

Answer (score 2):

It is a Firefox extension - so you have to open (and install) it in Firefox. Run Firefox, click the Firefox button, choose New Tab and then Open File. Choose the XPI file, installation should start then. Or you could just go to https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/donottrackplus/ with Firefox and click "Add to Firefox".

General note: most Firefox extensions are platform-agnostic. That means that they don't care which operating system you use, they run in Firefox. As long as you have the right Firefox version installed they will work. In case of Do Not Track Plus 2.0.8 anything from Firefox 3.6 to Firefox 12 is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file to .zip and open with your favorite decompresser.

.xpi files are zip files created by/for packaging Java plugins for Mozilla.

If you have 7zip (or really anything besides the built-in Windows extractor) you shouldn't even need to rename the file. Just right-click and tell 7zip to extract the file.

Details: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility

Comment: Changing compatibility isn't necessary - that add-on is compatible to the current Firefox version ;)

Comment: I know, that's just the first page I found that showed what I was talking about, converting to .zip and extracting. Actually, that's the page I found 9 years ago when I first started building Firefox search extensions and tweaking plugins that weren't up-to-date.